# To show that if B is a subset of A that B interior is a subset of A interior

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Hi Guys i have to prove the following;-

$$if ,B \subseteq A, B^0 \subseteq A^0$$

Can i say the following

$$A = A^0,A\subseteq A^0$$

$$B = B^0,B\subseteq B^0$$

$$\implies B^0 \subseteq A^0 $$

I was wondering if this is not valid and i was hoping for some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a valid argument. You are not told that $A=A^{0}$ and $B=B^{0}$.

To prove this let  $x \in B^{0}$. Then there is an open set $U$ such that $x \in U \subseteq B$. This implies $x \in U \subseteq A$ and hence $x \in A^{0}$.

Comment: $$y \in B(x,\epsilon)^0$$ $$d(x,y) < \epsilon$$ y is an arbitrary point in B $$B(x,\epsilon)^0 \subseteq A$$ $$\implies y \in A$$ $$B^0 \subseteq A^0$$ is this valid?

Comment: @Amir No. You have to start with $y \in B^{0}$ and prove that  $y \in A^{0}$

Comment: ok thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is invalid, making unwarranted extraneous assumptions.

However, if $A\subseteq B$, then $A^\circ \subseteq A$ is an open set contained in $B$, and as $B^\circ$ is the *largest* open set contained in $B$, we have that $A^\circ \subseteq B^\circ$, as required.

Comment: the question is to show $B^0 \subseteq A^0$

Comment: @Amir interchange the rôles of $A$ and $B$. Naming of variables is irrelevant.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying that